# loop inside loop is not working in handlebars

Tags: jquery, html, handlebars.js

Am using handlebars in my project.I have 2 objects which gonna pass to templates..outermost loop only working, inner loop is not working.

My js code

```
var ListCount =[{},{},{}];
var ListValues =[{height: "12"},{height: "13"},{height: "14"}];
```

So am passing this value in my template like this

```
<tbody id="flavandMapTable" class="table-body">
{{#each ListCount }}
        <tr> <td class="column">
       <select class="input-option-call " >
    <option>Select</option>
        {{#each ListValues }}                       
        <option value="{{height}}">{{height}}</option>
        {{/each}}                       
    </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

i can able to get 3 rows but the values inside rows are not coming.May i know what i did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the my working code,

```
 var list = {}
list.ListCount=[{height: "1"},{height: "2"},{height: "3"}];
list.ListValues=[{height: "12"},{height: "13"},{height: "14"}];

 {{#each list.ListCount}} 
 <tr> 
    <td class="column"> 
        <select class="input-option-call " >
            <option>Select</option>
                {{#each ../this/list.ListValues }}
                <option value="{{height}}">{{height}}</option>
                {{/each}}
            </select> 
    </td> 
 </tr> 
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone giving good reference. Especially rohan kumar

Answer (score 2):

I am not much familiar with `handlebar.js` but you can try this,

```
{{#each ListValues }}                       
    <option value="{{this.height}}">{{this.height}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Or make an `online demo` of your code.

**Updated** try this,

**Template**

```
<tbody id="flavandMapTable" class="table-body">
{{#each ListCount}}
  <tr><td class="column">
     <select class="input-option-call">
       <option>Select</option>
       {{#each ../this/ListValues}}
        <option>{{this.height}}</option>
       {{/each}}
     </select>
     </td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

**Javascript**

```
{
   "ListCount" :[{height: "1"},{height: "2"},{height: "3"}],
   "ListValues" :[{height: "12"},{height: "13"},{height: "14"}]
}
```

Tested on http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Comment: I tried on http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ and its working if I remove `Listcount each loop`.

Comment: ya for me also its working but i want loop inside loop..i want 3 rows with datas.

Comment: or else do i have any way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the context: the innermost `each` is searching for `ListValues` inside the `ListCount` (the outermost `each`).

I've never used two variables as context, but if this was a single context, like this:

```
{
    count: [ {}, {}, {} ],
    values: [
      { height: 12 },
      { height: 13 },
      { height: 14 }
    ]
}
```

... then the innermost `each` would be `{{#each ../values}}` to inform handlebars that the values are one level up from the current context (which is `count`).

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/8PeT4/).

Answer (score 0):

Handlebar will work with only one Context i.e. JSON. It won't work with two JSON's.

So with reference to @ssarabando, example context. You can change the Handlebar template as follows

**Context:**

```
{
    ListCount: [ {}, {}, {} ],
    ListValues: [
      { height: 12 },
      { height: 13 },
      { height: 14 }
    ]
}
```

**Handebar Template:**

```
<tbody id="flavandMapTable" class="table-body">
{{#each ListCount}}
        <tr> <td class="column">
       <select class="input-option-call " >
    <option>Select</option>
        {{#each ../ListValues}}                       
        <option value="{{height}}">{{height}}</option>
        {{/each}}                       
    </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}  
</tbody>
```